# how to bind click event to a clone button in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am working on an application which provides the facility of downloading couple of file from a jqGrid.

the jqGrid has several columns and one column which will display the download button for each row.
the user has to click on it and then the download will begin.
 for this download button i have used an 
html input tag in jsp as below,

```
<input type="button" id="download" height="30px" width="100px" value="Download">
```

and in my jqgrid code i am trying to clone this button as below.

```
{
  name:'click to download',
  index:'click to download',
  width:50,
  formatter: function(cellvalue, options, rowObject){
    var button = $("#download").clone(true);
    button.addClass(".button");
    $("body").on("click",".button",function(){
      alert("hello");
    });
    return button[0].outerHTML;
  },
  sortable: false
}
```

I want to write a  function separately for this cloned button on its click event and pass the parameter to that function such as rowId and cellvalue.

anyone please help me on this, I have tried creating function on this event button but they are not getting called. after which i tried to create a buttons manually instead of cloning but the click function still doesn't get called.
any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: IDs ***must*** be unique on document context, use class instead

Comment: By returning `button[0].outerHTML`, you are losing all associated data and events. You'd have better to provide an online sample as jsFiddle replicating your issue

Comment: I tried your solution too, but its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, try changing this:

`button.addClass(".button");`

to this (remove the prefixing period):

`button.addClass("button");`

Comment: This solution worked, But now on clicking a button i get alert equal to the number of rows, can you please tell me how to avoid this.

Comment: If you are adding one click event for each row, then you would get multiple alerts.  Instead, add just one click event when your page is loaded (outside of your jqgrid code), and that should get you a single alert.

Comment: But to that click event how will i pass the parameters. I need to pass the parameters to that function. can you please provide me any sample code for this. I need to pass complete row data to that function on click of button.

Answer (score 2):

you should use jquery "on" function because "on" keeps watching the click event in the dom, the simple click do not recognize the element that you just cloned

syntaxe:

```
$( "body" ).on( "click", ".your_element", function() {
   // your code here
});
```

**NOTE:** use classes instead of IDs.

Comment: I have changed the code as below, but still not working.

         var button = $("#download").clone(true);
           button.addClass(".button");
           $("body").on("click",".button",function(){
            alert("hello");
           });
                       return button[0].outerHTML;

Comment: Please see above, I have changed the code. I am not very proficient in writing Jquery code, so please help me.

Comment: can any one please tell me where i am missing.